# Limit a complex contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_{0}$ be a simple pole of $f$ and $\gamma_{r}$ an arc of circle centered on $z_{0}$, of the radius $r$ and angle $\alpha$, i.e., $\gamma_{r}=z_{0}+re^{it}$, with $t\in [\theta,\theta_{0}+\alpha]$, for some $\theta_{0}$.

Show that
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \int_{\gamma_{r}}{f(z)dz = i\alpha Res(f,z_{0})}$$

Comment: Any ideas, any advance, insights....?

Answer (score 0):

Since $z_0$ is a simple pole of $f$, we can write
$$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0},$$
where $g$ is holomorphic in a disc centered at $z_0$ and $g(z_0)\neq 0$. Note that $g(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=\mathrm{Res}_{z_0}f$, thus it's suffice to show that
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}=i\alpha g(z_0).$$
By direct calculation, we have
$$i\alpha g(z_0)=\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$
for every arc of circle $\gamma_r$ centered at $z_0$, of the radius $r$ and angle $\alpha$. Combining the two equality, it's suffice to show that
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\,dz=0.$$
But the eqaulity is easy to prove.(Note that $g$ is differentiable at $z_0$, thus $\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ is bounded in a small disc centered at $z_0$.)